# Send emails to a specific email address only when row is not empty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have a code that sends out emails to a specific email address (in this case lets say its myemailaddress@gmail.com) based on the values in my Google Sheet tab named 'Send Emails [Team A]'. It runs when I click on the menu item 'To Team A'. The code is sending out emails fine, however it also runs on rows that are blank, thus sending out blank emails to myemailaddress@gmail.com. The sheet will be updated from time to time which is why I did not limit the range until a specific row. Is there a way to make the code run only on rows that are not blank?

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu("Send Emails")
      .addItem("To Team A", "toTeamA")
      .addToUi();

// This constant is written in column C for rows for which an email
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = "Email Sent";

function toTeamA() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Send Emails [Team A]");
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process would be '2' because the first row is header
  var numRows = 1000; // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange('A2:D') // Gets the data range
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = "myemailaddress@gmail.com";
    var subject = row [1];      // Second column
    var message = row [0];      // First column
    var emailSent = row [2];    // Third column
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Makes sure cell is updated right away with "Email Sent" in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();  
    }
  }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, assuming your rows are empty, e.g. rows 1-100 contain content, whereas 101 onwards it is empty. You can find the last row with data using `sheet.getLastRow()`, see [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow).

So instead of doing `sheet.getRange("A2:D")` you can do `sheet.getRange("A2:D"+sheet.getLastRow())` which should fix the problem.